# OpenGL shader what is the default value of sampler2D

Tags: opengl, shader

I am very new to OpenGL and to shaders and I was experimenting a bit with sending multiple textures to shaders where I noticed something strange.

So here is what I had. I had a fragment shader that looked like this.

```
#version 440 core

in vec3 vs_position;
in vec3 vs_color;
in vec2 vs_texcoord;
in vec3 vs_normal;

out vec4 fs_color;

uniform sampler2D texture0;
uniform sampler2D texture1;


void main() {
    fs_color = texture(texture0, vs_texcoord) * texture(texture1, vs_texcoord);
}
```

and at some point I stopped sending data for texture1 but I forgot to remove the code from the shader. Obviously this was a bug and the program was not working as intended but what I noticed that the colors looked deeper and not as flat when I had this bug compared to when I fixed my code and removed texture1 related stuff from the shader.

So this is what I had

[image]

Now I understand that once I add proper lighting and all that the textures won`t look flat anymore but I am still confused as to what exactly is happening when I multiply the texture0 data (Texture that I actually set) with texture1 data (This is not being set).

What is the default value of sampler2D and what is causing this color shift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, samplers are bound to texture unit 0. I guess the look you got could be that you also attached texture unit 0 to `texture0` and basically multiply the texture with itself.

Comment: Ah, that makes so much sense. I tried doing fs_color = texture(texture0, vs_texcoord) * texture(texture0, vs_texcoord) and got the same result so indeed texture1 was getting the same texture as texture0.

Thanks.